How do I update tables in the database?
I have an database with ORM control by SQLAlchemy, but I have a problem: when I edited adding a new columns my database file don't updating and while code working old database in file brokes all work. For update database I need deleting my database file or adding new columns manually for fix this problem. How I can editing tables automaticly in my code?
My database:
from sqlalchemy import *
import sqlalchemy.orm as orm

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///database.db')

session = orm.Session(bind=engine)

Base = orm.declarative_base()
metadata: MetaData = Base.metadata

class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tests"
    test_id: int = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    test_column: str = Column(String, nullable=False, default="none")
    
metadata.create_all(engine)


Check alembic tool. It can automatically derive SQL update scripts based on your SQL alchemy model and the current SQL database.

This answer on the linked duplicate.
